# Could not parse the remainder: '{{request.LANGUAGE_CODE}}' from '{{request.LANGUAGE_CODE}}'

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I programing with django 1.11, now I have following script in post_list.html

```html
{% with lang={{request.LANGUAGE_CODE}} %}
{% endwith %}

           <p>
               {% if lang == 'zh-CN' %} {{object.category.name_zh_CN}} {% else %} {{object.category.name}} {% endif %}
           </p>
```

but I cannot get lang actually with following error message, please help.Thanks.

```html
TemplateSyntaxError at /adv/australia-strategic/
Could not parse the remainder: '{{request.LANGUAGE_CODE}}' from '{{request.LANGUAGE_CODE}}'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8030/adv/australia-strategic/
Django Version: 1.11.6
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: 
Could not parse the remainder: '{{request.LANGUAGE_CODE}}' from '{{request.LANGUAGE_CODE}}'
Exception Location: /Users/wzy/anaconda2/envs/python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in __init__, line 700
Python Executable: /Users/wzy/anaconda2/envs/python36/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.3
Python Path: 
['/Users/wzy/expo3/expo',
 '/Users/wzy/anaconda2/envs/python36/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Users/wzy/anaconda2/envs/python36/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/wzy/anaconda2/envs/python36/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/wzy/anaconda2/envs/python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/Users/wzy/expo3/expo']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double curly brackets are not needed within the `{% %}`, instead you can simply use the variable:

```
{% with lang=request.LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% endwith %}
<p>
    {% if lang == 'zh-CN' %} {{object.category.name_zh_CN}} {% else %} {{object.category.name}} {% endif %}
</p>
```

You can read more about this in the [django template guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/language/).

Comment: `lang` var will not work out of `with` templatetag scope

Comment: thanks I fully fixed this issue with your kindly assistance.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% with lang=request.LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    <p>
        {% if lang == 'zh-CN' %} {{object.category.name_zh_CN}} {% else %} {{object.category.name}} {% endif %}
    </p>
{% endwith %}
```

But you can simplify it:

```
<p>
    {% if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'zh-CN' %} {{object.category.name_zh_CN}} {% else %} {{object.category.name}} {% endif %}
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your simple alternative solution, clear so much.